# regex : string who don't have [/img]

Tags: regex

I have :

> [img]bl/a[/img][img]blafimgghfh/jhgjg[/img]

I would like to extract **bl/a** and **blafimgghfh/jhgjg**

For this, I need the regex who give me strings beetween **[img]** and **[/img]** and who doesn't include **[/img]**

> /[img](.*)[/img]/i

returns **bl/a[/img][img]blafimgghfh/jhgjg**

I have try

> /[img]([^[]+[^/]+[^i]+[^m]+[^g]+[^]]+)[/img]/i

but it doesn't works

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a [non-greedy match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for the inner contents.

```
\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]
```

Answer (score 2):

`\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]`

*? is the lazy star - it matches 0 or more times, and it matches as few as it can. (without the ? it is the greedy star - it matches as much as it can)

Learn more:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html